# How do I AJAX post to an MVC action from within a javascript file?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

The following code exists in a file called *job.js*. When I run this code against localhost everything behaves properly. When I do so against my intranet server where there is an application name I get a 404.

```
Job.updateJob = function () {

    $.post('/Builder/ListJobItems', function (data) {
        ...
    });
}
```

I would love to use `@Url.Action()` but as I said this is javascript (.js) file. I am also aware of the hack where you put a data value onto the body element, but for architectural reasons, I want this code to be decoupled from the DOM. It is a data acquisition engine, why should it even know what a DOM is.

I would be fine with a solution that parses `window.location` in some fashion, but the problem that I am having their is that I need a solution that will work everywhere.

What frustrates me most is that I can't see how this isn't a problem everyone would face. Why isn't there a solution? Does everyone just put all of their JavaScript into the razor view? Does no one isolate code into modules anymore? I can't believe either of these is true, and yet there don't seem to be any forth coming solutions for this. I am at a loss.

Comment: how about something DI-ish, like `Job.updateJob = function (url) {` ? (maybe where you call it from has razor, or maybe the place that calls the call has razor; going back far enough something HAS to right?)

Comment: I do this type of stuff and don't have problems. Something configured wrong on your intranet server? routing issue?

Comment: @zgood, I said why in my question. On localhost I don't have an application name. On the interanet server I do. The url '/Builder/ListJobItems' should be '/MyApplication/Builder/ListJobItems' when it is called against my that server. I need this code to work in both cases.

Comment: @Jordan oh must have missed that part lol

Answer (score 0):

What I have done when I need data to from server side in js files.

I create Action, and view with the JS content. And instead including job.js I call my action

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Action("Job","JSController")"/>
```

and in the view I set all, like

```
Job.updateJob = function () {

    $.post('@Url.Action("ListJobItems","Builder")', function (data) {
        ...
    });
}
```

and this will work.

Comment: This is a very interesting approach. I wasn't aware you could have JavaScript controllers.  What would such an action look like? I will have to do some research, but I think that this is exactly what I need.

Comment: There are no JavaScript controllers, its ordinarycontroller where action view doesn't contain HTML just JavaScript, same as .js file on server.

Comment: Is there any way to make the razor view use js syntax instead of html?